# Is assigning a method in the constructor good practice?

Tags: python, class-design

Here's a class with a method that calls different functions based on a parameter set in the constructor:

```
functions = {
    "arg1": f1,
    "arg2": f2,
    "arg3": f3
}

class C:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    def _util_method(self, v):
        return functions[self.arg](v)

    def method1(self, v):
        self._util_method(v)
    def method2(self, v):
        self._util_method(v)
```

I'm thinking of assigning `util_method` in the constructor depending on `arg`, to avoid the dictionary lookup at each call:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self._util_method = functions[arg]

    def method1(self, v):
        self._util_method(v)
    def method2(self, v):
        self._util_method(v)
```

The class would lose readability, since the "method" hasn't been declared as a regular method, and finding its declaration is harder for the reader. I remember losing time trying to read code like that from a uni teacher.

Is assigning a method to a class in the constructor good practice? If not, what would be the right way of doing this without unnecessary dictionary lookup?

Comment: Note that attribute access also involves a dictionary lookup (python classes are mostly just syntax sugar for dictionaries). Dictionaries are really fast in python though, and in most code it's unlikely to be the bottleneck. With that said, I generally prefer passing the functions directly into the constructor whenever possible, so you construct the class with `C(f1)`.

Comment: Why do you think that avoiding the dictionary lookup is something that needs to be done?